# publish topic through serial/usb

Tags: c++, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to publish three topics through usb connection to a custom pcb with an MSP432.

I need to use c++ as this if for safety critical vehicle control (Ford F-150) based on control outputs from Autoware.

I am having issues finding some examples on this as I do not have a lot of experience with C++.

I already have a program that does this in python. The only examples i found are 1000 lines of code and rather confusing to me at least.

Thanks!

EDIT: Where in autoware is VehicleCmd.h located? I am trying this in  a seperate catkin so i am not sure how to make sure catkin can find this file

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358119/publish-topic-through-serial/usb/) by [JoloGermanAg](https://answers.ros.org/users/53396/jologermanag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2020-07-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoloGermanAg](https://answers.ros.org/users/53396/jologermanag/) on 2020-07-27**:
I might have just found the answer at [github serial node](https://github.com/garyservin/serial-example/blob/master/src/serial_example_node.cpp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS1 does not support USB or Serial connections natively as transports for topics but nodes can communicate through USB or Serial on their own. The example you linked to is probably one of the best for this type of work.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoloGermanAg](https://answers.ros.org/users/53396/jologermanag/) on 2020-07-28**:
Thanks! It was actually way easier than I expected.

If anybody ever finds this thread here's an example that let's you use the autoware GUI. [Github](https://github.com/TheGermanKid/AutowareSerialOutput)